# Using almost with “half” in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I am confusing when using “almost” in a sentence.

> This figure was almost half (45%) for part-time student

I feel something wrong in this sentence but cannot understand clearly.

Comment: can you add some more context.  What does the 45% refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing very wrong with your placement of "almost" it modifies "half" so you would expect to place it close to the word "half".  You should use "students" (or "the part-time student if you are talking about a particular one)

The structural problem is that you make "the figure" the subject. We are probably not really interested in the numbers, we are interested in what the numbers mean for people.  Your sentence doesn't tell us this, so I can't fix it. But I can improve it by making the students the subject.

> Almost half (45%) of part-time students...
>
> Part-time students got less than half marks (45%)...